# Select item by specific property

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm working in Laravel 4, I can my models simplify to these:

```
class DayVariant extends \Eloquent {
    public function chod()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Chod', 'chod_id');
    }
}

class Chod extends \Eloquent {
    public function meals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Meal');
    }
 }

class Meal extends \Eloquent {
    public function mealProperties()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('MealsProperty');
    }
}

class MealProperty extends \Eloquent {
     public function propertyType()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('PropertyType', 'property_type_id');
     }
}
```

And I want select *MealProperty* by *property_type_id*. I was doing it this way:

```
$prop = $dayVariant->chod->meals->first()->mealProperties()->where('property_type_id','=', $foo)->first();
```

I need in this way get 5 from 70 the same *mealsProperties* for every meal. It works well, but I don't know how use eager loading for decreasing queries to database.

```
$dayVariant = DayVariant::with('breakfastChod.meals.mealProperties')->first();
```

I can do it this way and after it iterate over all *mealProperties*, but I'm looking for better way.
Maybe with constraints I can get only *mealProperties* which I will need and iterate over them. 
Is there better way to get specific properties? If not, how can use constraints with my models?
I tried this, but it fails.

```
$dayVariant = DayVariant::whereHas('breakfastChod.meals.mealProperties',    function($query)
{
     $query->where('property_type_id', '=', $constants['nutr_ids']['kcal']);
})->first();
```

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Do you have those ids of the MealProperties already? You need only these properties or all the related models?

Comment: Hi Deczo. Yes, I have _property_type_id_ of each property which I need and I need all related models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the context of property or like you tried of dayVariant:

```
// starting from properties
$properties = MealProperty::whereIn('property_type_id',$foo)
                 ->with('meal.chods.dayVariants')->get();

// or from dayVariant
$dayVariant = DayVariant::with(['chod.meals.mealProperties' => function ($q) use ($foo) {
  $q->whereIn('property_type_id', $foo);
}])->first();
```

Comment: It works for me, thank you very much! Still I have 52 queries, but better then 300 :)

Comment: Probably because I designed `DayVariant` model wrong. Instead of method `chod` I have in real `breakfastChod`, `tea-timeChod`, ..., `dinnerChod`. For each `***Chod` it does the same queries, so I think that if I will implement one method `chods` instead of before mentioned methods I can get circa 15 queries. What do you think?  Is it possible to join queries in actual model? Thank you @deczo

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/lz578 I copy everything important, sorry for length of code.